# SQL Error when using Order By for SQL database query in PowerBI Desktop

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, powerbi

Getting this error when using Get Data with PowerBI Desktop to connect to SQL database

Microsoft SQL: The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.

```
SELECT PromotionID, PromoDescription, PromoStartDate, 
    CASE
        WHEN PromoDescription LIKE '%QUINELLA%' OR
             PromoDescription LIKE '%EXACTA%' OR
             PromoDescription LIKE '%TRIFECTA%' OR
             PromoDescription LIKE '%FIRST FOUR%' THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END [Priority]
FROM TBS.dbo.Promotion WITH (NOLOCK) 
WHERE ArchivePartition IN (0,1)
  AND PromoDescription NOT LIKE '%QUINELLA%' 
  AND PromoDescription NOT LIKE '%EXACTA%' 
  AND PromoDescription NOT LIKE '%TRIFECTA%' 
  AND PromoDescription NOT LIKE '%FIRST FOUR%'

--AND PromoEndDate > getdate()-90
ORDER BY Priority ASC, PromoStartDate DESC'''
```

I saw I can change the top section to Top XXXXX e.g.,

```
SELECT Top 1000 PromotionID, PromoDescription, PromoStartDate
```

How can I return all results without using this hack?

Comment: Is this code from a View definition?

Comment: If it was a view I think he'd be seeing the problem when trying to compile the view.  I think this is a CTE.

Answer (score 0):

maybe This can give you your desired results

```
ORDER BY Priority ASC, PromoStartDate DESC OFFSET 0 ROWS
```